# How do I choose the correct power in a tweedie GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, tweedie-distribution

I'm developing a GLM with a tweedie family distribution.  How do I choose P correctly and how much does it matter?

I know it has to be between 1 and 2, and when I try different values, I don't see an improvement or decline in accuracy.

But if there is a correct way to choose, I'd like to know to pass on to my colleagues.

Thanks.

Comment: p does not "have to be between 1 and 2" for a Tweedie model. It should be quite possible to have a Tweedie GLM with p=2.4 for example. If you seek a Tweedie with particular features, then you might be more limited in your choice and particular implementations might limit you to particular values. You can't have values between 0 and 1 however.

Comment: I didn't know that.  What's the correct way to choose aside from trial and error?

Comment: I'm presently just addressing the premise of the question. If I was attempting an answer it would be an answer.

Comment: I would, however, highly recommend chapter 12 of Dunn and Smyth (2018), *Generalized Linear Models With Examples in R*. If I remember correctly it mentions at least two ways to choose the power parameter.

Comment: I'll see if my library has that book.  Thank you for the reference.

Comment: Wiki has a good discussion of Tweedie distributions, particularly the *Examples* section where the magnitude of the tail index is classified https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution That said, there's not a lot of agreement about the *best* way to estimate an index. The classic "go-to" approaches are Hill's and Pickand's methods but even those have been criticized as inaccurate, e.g., McElroy and Politis, *Moment-Based Tail Index Estimation* http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~politis/PAPER/jspi-tail.pdf  Gabaix's paper *Rank 1/2: A Simple Way to Improve the OLS Estimation of Tail Exponents*

Comment: Here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwhIiVlJjrAhUMxVkKHf36BRMQFjABegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpages.stern.nyu.edu%2F~xgabaix%2Fpapers%2Frank.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3iw3IfnbCOeYS1vZWbvLkg is among the easiest methods to estimating tail indexes. One approach would be to try several different methods and look for concordance in choosing an index.